# Downgrading gaming pc to NAS box

Tags: power-management, downgrade

I currently have an old gaming pc which I wish to turn into a NAS box.

Im aware and understand the way to install, im more interested in reducing power consumption.

I thought if i removed the Graphics card, Raptor Drives and 80% of the RAM would that be enough to reduce the power consumption and still allow the pc to work correctly?

The power supply is currently 1000w

Thanks

Comment: Why remove the RAM?  More is better.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a CPU that can do GPU tasks as well (Sandy Bridge, Fusion) you don't need a graphics card, else you will. Your current motherboard might have a built in GPU.

RAM can be reduced to one stick.

Drives are best replaced with 'green' versions that some manufacturers use, though drives don't use thát much power. Also set your drives to power off after 10 minutes of inactivity.

You should change the energy management to high performance, but turn off automatic sleep mode and enable the automatic downclocking of the CPU. There's also a setting for the minimum CPU frequency, set this to 5%.

A screen is only necessary during the installation of Windows, you can access it through remote desktop on another Windows PC after the installation.

The DVD reader/writer can also be taken out after the Windows Installation. You can use DVD emulation instead.

I'm not sure if the wattage of the PSU makes a difference, but I would downgrade to the minimum needed. Though I need confirmation on this one.

If you need further explanation on anything, let me know.